# Redirect packets and save the content to disk

Tags: networking, iptables

I want to reroute a connection just like `rinetd` does but save the client and server messages.

Is there any tool like this out there ? I'm using Debian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Background on rinetd

Looking at a simple example `rinetd.conf` file that I found here in this article titled: [Rinetd – redirects TCP connections from one IP address and port to another](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/rinetd-redirects-tcp-connections-from-one-ip-address-and-port-to-another.html):

```
# bindadress bindport connectaddress connectport
192.168.2.1 80 192.168.2.3 80
192.168.2.1 443 192.168.2.3 443
```

#### Redirecting with iptables

Something similar can be achieved with a rule such as this using `iptables`.

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 \
    -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.3:80
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 25 -j MASQUERADE
```

The above would redirect port 80 on your localhost (192.168.2.1) to the remote host (192.168.2.3). These rules are based on what I found here in this articled titled: [iptables Tips and Tricks - Port Redirection](http://blog.softlayer.com/2011/iptables-tips-and-tricks-port-redirection).

#### Logging packets with ulogd

Using the `ulogd` userspace logging daemon for netfilter you could add additional rules/switches to get the packets logging based on this articled titled: [Pulling packets out of the kernel](http://www.stearns.org/doc/iptables-ulog.v0.1.html). Assuming you've used your distros package management to install `ulogd` and started it:

```
$ sudo service ulogd start
```

The example from that article logs `ping` packets to address 99.99.99.99:

```
$ ping -c 5 99.99.99.99
$ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -d 99.99.99.99 -j ULOG --ulog-nlgroup 1 \
    --ulog-cprange 100
```

Then using `tcpdump` you can take a look at the log file that `ulogd` has been keeping in the file `/var/log/ulogd.pcap`.

```
$ sudo tcpdump -r /var/log/ulogd.pcap -qtnp
172.27.1.66 > 99.99.99.99: icmp: echo request (DF)
172.27.1.66 > 99.99.99.99: icmp: echo request (DF)
172.27.1.66 > 99.99.99.99: icmp: echo request (DF)
172.27.1.66 > 99.99.99.99: icmp: echo request (DF)
172.27.1.66 > 99.99.99.99: icmp: echo request (DF)
```

You can watch it live like so:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/ulogd.pcap | tcpdump -r - -qtnp
```

To watch your packets you'd need to change the above `iptables` rule as needed.